# How to set bootstrap col for small display sizes?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have the following Bootstrap code:

```
<div>
<div class="col-md-5"></div>
<div class="col-md-7"></div>
</div>
```

How to display these two blocks in full width in small displays?
Now it displayed under each other.

**Now**

```
1
2
```

**Required**

**`1 2`**

Comment: `col-xs` instead of `col-md`

Comment: Try adding col-sm-6 col-xs-6 to both divs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div>
    <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-5"></div>
    <div class="col-md-7 col-sm-7 col-xs-7"></div>
</div>
```

You have to declare the size of your col for the @media less than medium

Extra small devices Phones (<768px) - col-xs-* 
Small devices Tablets (≥768px) - col-sm-* 
Medium devices Desktops (≥992px) - col-md-* 
Large devices Desktops (≥1200px) - col-lg-*

Comment: if all have the same col-N then no need for bigger ones, just `col-xs` would be enough

Comment: Can you comment what does it mean each property?

Comment: I just edit my answer

Comment: The extra classes are unnecessary, and -xs- isn't used in Bootstrap 4

Answer (score 1):

In **Bootstrap 4**, use the xs breakpoint for non stacking columns. This is the default breakpoint so you don't need to use the `xs` infix in your markup...

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-5">1</div>
    <div class="col-7">2</div>
</div>
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/uui5COCcbT